# Считывать данные из стандартного ввода

Tags: golang

Возникла проблема во время знакомства с go: как в цикле считать построчно весь stdin используя `fmt.Scanln(&str)`, если он возвращает 2 значения

```
for fmt.Scanln(&str) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

такой вариант естественно выдает ошибку и все что приходит в голову это переместить вызов `fmt.Scanln(&str)` внутрь цикла, а в условие поместить проверку по одному из возвращаемых значений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться трёхинструкционным `for`:

```golang
for _, err = fmt.Scanln(&str); err == nil; _, err = fmt.Scanln(&str) {
        fmt.Println(str)
}

if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, ожидал нечто более емкое) Пока не могу понять, есть ли принципиальное отличие `fmt.Scanln` и `bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)`
Нашел еще один вариант
```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
```

Comment: ЕМНИП, `fmt.Scan` и иже с ними не буферизует поток.  Ну и если вам нужно именно сканировать текст, а не считывать какие-то ответы пользователя, то лучше всё же наверное сканер.

Answer (score 1):

Вы всегда можете воспользоваться буферизированным reader и делать это в цикле:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(text)
}
```